# Why does errexit in bash ignore an arithmetic expansion divide-by-zero?

Tags: bash

I dont understand why my below code is not exiting on error...

```
set -e
echo $((10/0))
```

output:

```
-bash: 10/0: division by 0 (error token is "0")
```

After running above code `echo $?` returns 1

Comment: Do you really include the backticks, or was that an attempt at code markup that you fixed by indenting the code now?

Comment: It appears from semi-casual experimentation that (for better or worse) Bash does not treat the arithmetic expansion as 'a command that fails' and therefore does not exit on error.  It does set `$?` to `1` on the failure, so you could explicitly test that.  The manual is quiet on whether this is really expected behaviour.

Comment: `ksh` also doesn't exit on this error, but `zsh` does.

Comment: `set -e` is not by any means universally considered a robust, reliable, well-considered and desirable feature. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- skipping the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry.

Comment: Also https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/, comparing `set -e` behavior across different shells (hint: different implementations are wildly incompatible with each other). Injecting my own opinions here, but -- do your own explicit error-handling; `set -e` has too many caveats, corner cases and incompatibilities to be trustworthy.